# Sending s3 bucket image resource to front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, cors

I want to be able to set my GET resource route to the src attribute of a HTML image tag so it makes a GET request to my api, the the api will fetch the image data from my s3 bucket and respond to my front-end with the image data, My front-end must know nothing about the true origin of the image.

When I test it in vs code with the rest client extension It works fine I get the image rendered in vs Code but when I try to call the route from my front-end I get this error.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin

My front-end already is fetching resources from my database via my api, I have cors setup so the origin should not be an issue.

I have tried to specifically set the origin in cors express library but still is not working.